# App Availability on Google Play Store by Location for visiting Clients

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an android app that is only Available in Philippines. But I have an query from my clients that this app is not showing them when they visiting in philippines from another country. I want to app should be available for all customers when they are in Philippines but not available to other countries.

Comment: You should ask this question to Google play help support .

Comment: it is impossible. The country is determined by the country, which the account is registered for. If the account is registered for USA, and you visit Philipines - the account will still belong to USA

Comment: @ADM I already asked this question on Google play help support but still didn't get any reply.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Can you share any official document link that mention this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Google Play and got solution on Google play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done at the moment. Google gets the country not from the geographic location but from the registered country for the account.

If you wanted a workaround a second Google account could be created for the Philippines while they are visiting, and that second account added to their phone. We know this isn't an ideal experience